# Redis server and its fork() - when the vm_enough_memory is called?

Tags: c, linux, redis, fork, system-calls

I'm trying to understand how the `fork()` is working in the Redis server running on Linux and how Redis will generate the ***fork: Cannot allocate memory*** response.

From what I inverstigated I see the next:

**1** redis-server calls `fork()` in its [`rdbSaveBackground()`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/rdb.c#L1342):

`if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {`

**2** This calls a `fork()` from the glibc's `sysdeps/nptl/fork.c` (which seems to be in the `/usr/lib/libc.so.6`):

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/redis-server
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffde8d93000)
    libjemalloc.so.2 => /usr/lib/libjemalloc.so.2 (0x00007fa5da60b000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa5da4c5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa5da4c0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa5da49f000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa5da2dc000)
```

*But I'm not sure the `ldd` is the right way to check it.
The `ltrace` only displays the `fork()` itself - but not the source from where it was called.*

**3** [`sysdeps/nptl/fork.c`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/nptl/fork.c#L76) executes the `arch_fork` macro

**4** And then [`sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arch-fork.h`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arch-fork.h#L32) calls exactly the `clone()` Linux syscall:

```
ret = INLINE_SYSCALL_CALL (clone, flags, 0, NULL, 0, ctid);
```

Which can be seen in a `strace`'s output:

> ```
> accept(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60816), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [128->16]) = 6
> ...
> stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2097, ...}) = 0
> clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,
> child_tidptr=0x7ff26beda190) = 1790
> ```

If so - when then `vm_enough_memory` is executed?

It must rise the Redis' famous "***Can't save in background: fork: Cannot allocate memory***".

I was able to find the `vm_enough_memory` in the Linux's [`fork()`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/fork.c#L528) syscall:

The `security_vm_enough_memory_mm`:

```
        if (security_vm_enough_memory_mm(oldmm, len)) /* sic */
            goto fail_nomem;
```

Desribed in the `include/linux/security.h`:

```
static inline int security_vm_enough_memory_mm(struct mm_struct *mm, long pages)
{
    return __vm_enough_memory(mm, pages, cap_vm_enough_memory(mm, pages));
}
```

So, the questions are (yeah, I know it's bad post two Q's in the same topic, but they are tied):

1. What is the correct way to see library functions calls by a process (besides the `ltrace` and `ldd` I used)
2. What about glibc's `fork()` and Linux `clone()`? How would Redis produce the *fork: Cannot allocate memory* if it is really uses 
   glibc's `fork()`?

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction, and Redis will call the Linux `fork()` syscall? If so - this will explain everything (but not the `strace`'s output with the `clone()`...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redis server and its fork() - when the vm_enough_memory is called?

Redis doesn't directly call `vm_enough_memory` - it simply calls the `fork` wrapper in glibc which in turn calls into kernel's fork system call (which is `clone` system call on all modern Linux kernels).

> What is the correct way to see library functions calls by a process (besides the ltrace and ldd I used)

`ltrace` is fine to get the library calls. `ldd` lists the shared library dependencies but doesn't tell you which library a given function resides. You may find [`nm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) and [`objdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) utilities useful in that regard.

> If so - when then vm_enough_memory is executed?

`vm_enough_memory` is a kernel function - strace or other tools will not list them. `strace` is usually good enough (unless you are the debugging the kernel itself) for applications to find out which system calls are being called by the user code and/or C library.

For example, `strlen` function is defined (it's in the text section, so you know it's defined there) in the C library:

```
 $ objdump -T  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep strlen
000000000007fd10 g   iD  .text  000000000000003d  GLIBC_2.2.5 strlen
```

(Read man page for various options).

> What about glibc's fork() and Linux clone()? How would Redis produce the fork: Cannot allocate memory if it is really uses glibc's fork()?

Again, you are complicating things. Redis simply calls `fork()` and if it returns -1 (fork failure) then it simply prints that error message based on the `errno` value.

That particular message [comes from this line of code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/rdb.c#L1370):

```
   serverLog(LL_WARNING,"Can't save in background: fork: %s",
            strerror(errno));
```

When fork fails, `childpid` is -1 and the `errno` is set by it indicating the error. When `errno` is set to `ENOMEM`, you get `Cannot allocate memory` error message.

Here's a simple example demonstraing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    printf("errno (ENOMEM): %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

And it outputs:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c11 test.c
$ ./a.out
errno (ENOMEM): Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Can I ask you please about the next: _"Redis simply calls fork() and if it returns -1 (fork failure)"_ - so, from where the `-1` comes to this `fork()` call? If I'm right that glib'c `fork()` calls the `clone()` syscall, then the `clone()` must return an error - is this correct?

Comment: `-1` is the return value of the `fork()` call on failure. Precisely where it gets set isn't important (usually the kernel returns a negative errno to glibc which is then to the appropriate `errno` value in userspace). That `fork()` return -1 on failure, 0 in the child process, pid in the parent is all that needs to be checked. And that's what Redis does.

Comment: I don't know if you're debugging a memory issues with Redis. If so, ["Background saving fails with a fork() error under Linux even if I have a lot of free RAM!"](https://redis.io/topics/faq) might be relevant.

Comment: Well... The thing is that I'm trying exactly yo understand from where the OS will return an error to the glib's `fork()` and particularly - why setting the `overcommit_memory == 1` has to solve it. E.g. - the OS has to execute the `__vm_enough_memory()` function to check as a "last" step after the glibc's `fork()` is executed. So - what happens "between"?

Comment: glibc simply sets the `errno` value based on the return code from kernel. `overcommit_memory` is completely a kernel mechanism and the glibc doesn't know/care about it.
When you set it to 1 (always overcommit), then [__vm_enough_memory](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fa121bb3fed6313b1f0af23952301e06cf6d32ed/mm/util.c#L695) always returns 0.

Comment: Um... Okay... So: 1. glibc `fork()`'s; 2. `fork()` calls => `clone()`; 3. `clone()` => [_something in the kernel here whith the `overcommit_memory`_]; 4. kernel `err` => `clone()`; 5. `clone() -1` => `fork()`; 6. redis fails. 
So - what's is going on in the phase *3*? :-)

Comment: Your sequence is correct. The answer to 3 lies in the functions linked :) (`__vm_enough_memory`, `security_vm_enough_memory_mm`, ...). It checks whether there are sufficient pages to be allocated (if `overcommit_memory` is 0 - which is the default) for the new process. When you set `overcommit_memory`  to 1, it doesn't ( e.g., RAM might be available when the new process modifies those pages; If not, it might fail at that stage -- the linked Redis faq explains this well). You are telling the kernel not to bypass that check.

Comment: :-D Okay! Cool. But still! Who and when will call the `__vm_enough_memory`? The `strace`'s output doesn't show any `mmap` or similar calls which could, in theory, ask the kernel to run the `__vm_enough_memory`. Althoguht `clone()` is called without the `CLONE_VM` - and as per my understanding - the kernel has to reserve some mem for the child process and during that - can call the `__vm_enough_memory`. (I'm sorry for such a long thread - but really want to undestand what is going on under the hood :-) ).

Comment: But... Maybe I can't see any allocations in the `strace` just because there is no any changes in the parent's memory, thus CoW wasn't "triggered"... But I don't see the `CLONE_VM`: _"If CLONE_VM is set, the calling process and the child process run in the same memory space"_, thus - they have to use separate mem => must be some `mmap`?